# Can you use a shared_ptr for RAII of C-style arrays?

Tags: c++, raii, shared-ptr

I'm working on a section of code that has many possible failure points which cause it to exit the function early.  The libraries I'm interacting with require that C-style arrays be passed to the functions.  So, instead of calling delete on the arrays at every exit point, I'm doing this:

```
void SomeFunction(int arrayLength)
{
   shared_ptr<char> raiiArray(new char[arrayLength]);
   pArray = raiiArray.get();

   if(SomeFunctionThatRequiresCArray(pArray) == FAILED) { return; }

   //etc.
}
```

I wanted to use `unique_ptr`, but my current compiler doesn't support it and the reference count overhead doesn't really matter in this case.

I'm just wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this practice when interfacing with legacy code.

**UPDATE**  I completely forgot about the `shared_ptr` calling `delete` instead of `delete []`.  I just saw no memory leaks and decided to go with it.  Didn't even think to use a vector.  Since I've been delving into new (for me) C++ lately I'm thinking I've got a case of the "If the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail." syndrome.  Thanks for the feedback.

**UPDATE2** I figured I'd change the question and provide an answer to make it a little more valuable to someone making the same mistake I did.  Although there are alternatives like `scoped_array`, `shared_array` and `vector`, you can use a `shared_ptr` to manage scope of an array (but after this I have no idea why I would want to):

```
template <typename T>
    class ArrayDeleter
    {
    public:
        void operator () (T* d) const
        {
            delete [] d;
        }
    };

void SomeFunction(int arrayLength)
    {
       shared_ptr<char> raiiArray(new char[arrayLength], ArrayDeleter<char>());
       pArray = raiiArray.get();

       if(SomeFunctionThatRequiresCArray(pArray) == FAILED) { return; }

       //etc.
    }
```

Comment: nitpicking: [[shared_ptr]] does not work correctly on dynamic array pointers. use [[scoped_array]] or [[shared_array]].

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do not use `shared_ptr` or `scoped_ptr` to hold pointers to dynamically allocated arrays. shared_ptr and scoped_ptr use `delete ptr;` to clean-up when the pointer is no longer referenced/goes out of scope, which invoked undefined behaviour on a dynamically allocated array. Instead, use shared_array or scoped_array, which correctly use `delete[] ptr;` when destructing.

To answer your question, if you are not going to pass the smart pointer around, use `scoped_array`, as it has less overhead than `shared_array`.

Alternatively, use `std::vector` as the array storage (vectors have guaranteed contiguous memory allocation).

Comment: By default, shared_ptr and scoped_ptr use delete ptr, but you can provide your own deleter function or functor.

Comment: One more disadvantage is unable to use `[]` operator. eg: cannot use `raaiArray[index]` instead `raaiArray.get()[index]`

Answer (score 15):

Use `boost::scoped_array`, or even better `std::vector` if you are dealing with an array.

Answer (score 7):

I highly recommend simply using a `std::vector`.  Elements in `vectors` are allocated on the heap, and will be deleted when the `vector` goes out of scope, wherever you exit the function.

In order to pass a `vector` to legacy code requiring C-style arrays, simply pass `&vectorName[0]`.  The elements are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory.

Comment: Ensure the vector is not empty before using `&vectorName[0]` or `&vectorName.front()`, since it's undefined or asserting behavior for some implementations.

Answer (score 6):

Some remarks for C++11 users:

For `shared_ptr`, there is in C++11 a default deleter for array types defined in `<memory>` and standard compliant (wrt the final draft) so it can be used without additional fancy deleters for such cases:

```
std::shared_ptr<char> raiiArray(new char[arrayLength], std::default_delete<char[]>());
```

`unique_ptr` in C++11 has a partial specialization to deal with `new[]` and `delete[]`. But it does not have a shared behavior, unfortunately. Must be a good reason there is no such specialization for `shared_ptr` but I didn't look for it, if you know it, please share it.

Comment: According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8947700/1094609), the ultimate reason there's no array specialization for `shared_ptr` is that "[T]here was never an actual written proposal in front of the LWG to do this."

Answer (score 5):

There's [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) for this.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
shared_ptr<char*> raiiArray(new char[arrayLength]);
```

is not a good practice, but causes undefined behaviour, as you allocate with operator `new[]`, but `shared_ptr` uses `operator delete` to free the memory. The right thing to use is `boost::shared_array` or add a custom deleter.