# Why isn't there a std::shared_ptr<T[]> specialisation?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, language-design

The standard provides a template specialization of `std::unique_ptr` which correctly calls the `delete[]` from its destructor:

```
void func()
{
   std::unique_ptr< int[] > arr(new int[10]);

   .......
}
```

With `std::shared_ptr` this specialisation is not available, so it is necessary to
to provide a deleter which correctly calls `delete[]`:

```
void func()
{
    // Usage
    shared_ptr array (new double [256], [](double* arr) { delete [] arr; } ); 

    ..............
}
```

Is this simply an oversight? (in the same way that there is an `std::copy_if`) or is there a reason?

Comment: N.B. there's a new proposal to add this for C++17, based on work in Boost, see http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3640.html

Comment: Notice that a lot of the `shared_ptr` machinery should be disabled when working with arrays, such as the ability to refer to a subobject.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The LWG (Library Working Group of the C++ committee) briefly considered the possibility but the idea wasn't without controversy.  Though the controversy was mainly about a feature added to the `shared_ptr<T[]>` proposal that could have been jettisoned (arithmetic on `shared_ptr<T[]>`).

But ultimately the real real reason is that though it was discussed, there was never an actual written proposal in front of the LWG to do this.  It never bubbled up anyone's priority list (including my own) sufficiently to put the time into writing a proposal.

Informal conversations have recently begun anew on this topic among a few LWG members, and I have personally prototyped it.  But there is still no written proposal for it.  I think it would be a decent additional tool in the toolbox.  Whether it will ever actually happen or not is anyone's guess.

**Update**

Array support for `shared_ptr` now has a draft TS:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4077.html

**Update (2017)**

This is now supported in C++17. See case 3 of [`shared_ptr::shared_ptr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Comment: First "why isn't there..." question with a real answer that I've seen, also, a dynamically allocated array? With vector and std::array, really don't see the need(?)

Comment: @Nim:  `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` (which exists) is good for when overhead is tremendously important to you.  Unlike `vector<T>`, `unique_ptr<T[]>` does not include overhead for capacity, or even size.  The client will probably need to add external overhead for size, but if the array is never resized, not for capacity.  Now this doesn't make `unique_ptr<T[]>` a better `vector<T>`.  Indeed, I think the use cases of the former will be rare compared to the latter.  But the use case rate isn't zero for the former.

Comment: Analogously, `shared_ptr<T[]>` can sometimes replace `shared_ptr<vector<T>>` with lower overhead.  The mere existence and continued support of `boost::shared_array<T>` is an argument that some programmers find such a tool occasionally useful.

Comment: Trivia:  The `unique_ptr<T[]>` syntax was born in 2001 on comp.lang.c++ by this interesting question about `auto_ptr`:  http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_thread/thread/469fcc136b8f2d42/f774bf6f81dd2af7?lnk=gst&q=auto_ptr%3CT%5B%5D%3E#f774bf6f81dd2af7

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I don't see the advantage of `shared_ptr<T[]>(new T[99])` over `make_shared<vector<T>>(99)`. In both cases we can expect two allocations and the overhead needed to make vector self-aware about its capacity and size is probably negligible.

Comment: @sellibitze: The benefit of the `shared_ptr<T[]>` version is that it only requires one pointer dereference to get to any of the array elements, while `shared_ptr<vector<T>>` requires two (one for the `shared_ptr`, one for the array stored in the `vector`).

Comment: @JeremiahWillcock: Point taken. But I suppose it's possible to save this first dereference operation (at least for most element accesses) by using iterators during a loop or something like this.

Comment: Consider a serial port class that calls a functor when a complete message is read but the size differs from message to message.  Since you read the data as a byte array, it would be more convenient to transfer the data as shared_ptr<unsigned char*> than anything else.

Comment: Is there a reason, why everyone seems to ignore shared_ptr<std::array<T,N>>? Is there any downside compared to shared_ptr<T[]> that I overloked?