# How to make a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I want to make a copy constructor for this class RNA to copy the details form another object RNA

```
#include "RNA.h"
#include"Sequence.h"
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
RNA::RNA()
{
    set_sequence();
}

RNA::RNA(char * seq, RNA_Type atype)
{
    int x;
    int i=0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(seq[i] != 'C'&&seq[i] != 'G'&&seq[i] != 'A'&&seq[i] != 'U')break;
        x++;
        i++;
    }
    x--;
    length = x;
    this->seq = new char[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        this->seq[i] = seq[i];
    }
    type = atype;
}
```

this is the copy constructor

```
RNA::RNA( RNA& rhs)
{
    seq = new char[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        seq[i] = rhs.seq[i];
    }
    type  = rhs.type;
}
```

in the main I try to do it and it make error

```
    int l;
     cin>>l;
     char* arr = new char[l];
     for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
     {
         cin>>arr[i];
     }
     cin>>l;
      RNA anas(arr,(RNA_Type)l);
  int s;
     cin>>s;
     char* arr2 = new char[s];
     for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
     {
         cin>>arr2[i];
     }
     cin>>s;
     RNA saeed(arr2,(RNA_Type)s);
     saeed(anas);  error is here 
      saeed.Print();
```

The error is " No match for call to '(RNA) (RNA&)'
so what can i do to solve this error

Comment: First please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (and probably [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) as well).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius [Not necessarily.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683959/can-a-copy-constructor-take-a-non-const-parameter)

Comment: Also, please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, and copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question (as text).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - `RNA::RNA(RNA &rhs)` is a copy constructor.   However, it cannot be used to copy a `const` object.

Comment: @Peter Or temporary objects.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -  yep

Comment: i am still study c++ so i cannot know every thing

Comment: To add another hint to the comment by @CinCout, the error message should actually contain exactly what is happening, and what is being ***called***.

Comment: @Asu Today I learned.. What I learned in addition to that, is that copy-constructor might have multiple arguments (if other arguments have default values).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to let the compiler do it for you.

```
class RNA
{
    RNA_Type type;
    std::string seq;
public:
    RNA(std::string = /* default seq */, RNA_Type = /* default type */);

    /* implicitly generated correctly
    ~RNA();
    RNA(const RNA &);
    RNA & operator = (const RNA &);
    RNA(RNA &&);
    RNA & operator = (RNA &&);
    */

    // other members
};

RNA::RNA(std::string aseq, RNA_Type atype)
 : seq(aseq.begin(), aseq.find_first_not_of("ACGT")), type(atype)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

`saeed` already exists at that point, and you're trying to use it as if it were a function.
You can't copy-construct except when you are constructing, and it looks like any other initialisation:

```
RNA saeed(anas);
```

or:

```
RNA saeed{anas};
```

If you want to replace the value of an already existing object, you use assignment (and you need to implement that assignment; read about [The Rule Of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
saeed(anas);
```

is not a call to the constructor `RNA::RNA(RNA const&)`, but to  `RNA::operator()(RNA const&)`, which does not exist.

What you presumably want is a **copy assignement operator**

```
RNA& RNA::operator=(RNA const&);
```

which for simple enough classes will be auto-generated by the compiler (as explained in Caleth's answer). To call it, replace your line with

```
saeed = anas;
```