# Cannot use class constructor using equals sign notation when class copy constructor is deleted

Tags: c++, constructor

While testing some classes I run into an interesting problem: When invoking class constructor using the equals sign notation (=) if the copy constructor is deleted an error is encountered **error: copying variable of type 'Class' invokes deleted constructor**. While using the parenthesis the code compiles normally.

**What is going on here? Can this be a compiler bug?**

Consider the following class:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        int Int;

    public:
        Test() = default;
        Test(Test &) = delete;
        Test(Test &&) = delete;
        Test(int i)
        {
            Int = i;
        }
};
```

Constructors invoked like so:

```
Test t1(3);  //No error
Test t2 = 3; //error: copying variable of type 'Class' invokes deleted constructor
```

Just to check I tried to add some checks and allow these functions and compile the code. 
Both constructors compiled **using MSVC** in the **exact same way**.

```
class Test
{
    public:
        int Int;

    public:
        Test()
        {
            Int = 0;
            cout << "Constructor";
        }
        Test(Test &t)
        {
            Int = t.Int;
            cout << "Copy Constructor";
        }
        Test(Test &&t)
        {
            Int = t.Int;
            cout << "Move Constructor";
        }
        Test(int i)
        {
            Int = i;
            cout << "Constructor from int";
        }
};
```

```
Test t1(3);  //Constructor from int
Test t2 = 3; //Constructor from int
```

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: This is *not* C#. Looks like C++.

Comment: Lets take a step back here... You need to work out what language you are in (as you seem confused and it will hinder your research)

Comment: Oh I am so sorry, I put the wrong tag! I will change it ASAP

Comment: That's not the `=` operator; that's initialization (by copy).

Comment: Great suggestion by @Chris Dodd! This is certainly very close to the answer. Though I dont quite understand in the first paragraph of explanation is stated: "The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible, as the language rules ensure that no copy/move operation takes place, even conceptually:" but in the first paragraph under the explanation is stated: "This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy/move (since C++11) constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all),". I dont understand the ambiguity.

Comment: Note that the copy ctor is *usually* `Test(const Test &)` -- while you can define it without the const, doing so [has some subtle effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683959/can-a-copy-constructor-take-a-non-const-parameter) which are usually undesirable (particularly since the introduction of rvalue/move semantics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the results of the [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) rule.

Basically, saying `T var = expr;` constructs an unnamed temp from `expr` and then copies or moves it into `var` using the copy or move construtor.  If the copy and move constructors are deleted, then this gives an error about the deleted constructor.  But then, the compiler is *required* to elide that copy or move and construct `var` directly from `expr`, even if the copy or move constructor has visible side effects.  Its one of those weird corner cases that arises from language design by de-facto standardization of what disparate implementations do (or did at some time in the past), plus design-by-committee and slow evolution over time while trying to keep backwards compatibility.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) for more discussion