# Strange behavior of gcc. Are C++ object definitions with {} and = equal or not?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm testing possibility to translate simulation done in Processing into C++.
But something strange happened:

```
class World {
  public:
    sarray<pAnt>    dummy1 { new array<pAnt>(10) };//OK
    sarray<pAnt>    dummy2 = new array<pAnt>(10);  //Compiler error?!?!?!*
    smatrix<pAnt>   dummyWorld1 { new matrix<pAnt>(100,100) };//OK
    smatrix<pAnt>   dummyWorld2 = new matrix<pAnt>(100,100);//OK
    smatrix<int>    ants = new matrix<int>(50,2);// OK
...
};
```

- ERROR:

  > /data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/klasaWorld.pde.cpp:27:
  >
  > error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type
  > ‘Processing::sarrayProcessing::ptr<Ant >&’ to an rvalue of type
  > ‘Processing::sarrayProcessing::ptr<Ant >’
  >
  > ```
  >  sarray<pAnt>    dummy2 = new array<pAnt>(10) ;//Compiler error?!?
  > ```

"Verbose" compiler output:

> [1/2 3.5/sec] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o
> FAILED:
> CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o
> /usr/bin/g++  -DDEF_MAXTHREADS=16 -DMULTITR -DVERSION_NUM=0.1
> -I/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc -I/home/borkowsk/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/../../scripts/../lib/include
> -I/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/symShell2/WBRTM_Linux -I/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/symShell2/WBRTM_Linux/INCLUDE --verbose -std=c++11 -pthread -MD -MT CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o
> -MF CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o.d
> -o CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o
> -c /data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp
> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
> OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1 Target:
> x86_64-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
> --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-D' 'DEF_MAXTHREADS=16' '-D' 'MULTITR' '-D'
> 'VERSION_NUM=0.1' '-I'
> '/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc'
> '-I'
> '/home/borkowsk/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/../../scripts/../lib/include'
> '-I' '/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/symShell2/WBRTM_Linux' '-I'
> '/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/symShell2/WBRTM_Linux/INCLUDE' '-v'
> '-std=c++11' '-pthread' '-MD' '-MT'
> 'CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o'
> '-MF'
> 'CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o.d'
> '-o'
> 'CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o'
> '-c' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1plus -quiet -v -I
> /data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc -I
> /home/borkowsk/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/../../scripts/../lib/include
> -I /data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/symShell2/WBRTM_Linux -I /data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/symShell2/WBRTM_Linux/INCLUDE
> -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -MD CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.d
> -MF CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o.d
> -MT CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o
> -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D DEF_MAXTHREADS=16 -D MULTITR -D VERSION_NUM=0.1
> /data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp
> -quiet -dumpbase project_at_once.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/MROWKI_0.1_once.dir/data/wb/SCC/__working_copies/Processing2C/PROJECTS/MROWKI/cppsrc/project_at_once.cpp.o
> -std=c++11 -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccaH1ylE.s

**GNU C++11 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) version 7.5.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
compiled by GNU C version 7.5.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP**
^

Here is the problem extracted from my project. Looks like one line is guilty, but I don't understand why :-)

```
#include <memory>

namespace Processing
{
   
template<class T>
class ptr
{
      //std::shared_ptr<T> _ptr;
  public:
      ptr();
      ptr(ptr<T>&);
      //ptr(const ptr<T>&);//This removes the error, but can not be implemented properly!
};

template<class T>
class array
{     
      //T* content;
  public:
      ~array();
      array(size_t N);
};

template<class T>
class sarray
{     // When the following line is commented out the error disapper!
      // so what is missing in ptr<T> ?  
      ptr< array<T> > _arr;//opaque smart ptr to array
      //std::shared_ptr< array<T> > _arr;//std smart pointer is OK
  public:
      ~sarray(){}
      sarray(){}
      sarray(array<T>* tab);
      sarray<T>& operator = (array<T>* tab);
};

}

using namespace Processing;


void example()
{  
  sarray<bool>          test1 = new array<bool>(2);// Compiler error?
  sarray<bool>          test2;

  test2 = new array<bool>(2);//OK
  
  sarray<bool>   test3 { new array<bool>(2) };//OK      
}
```

Comment: After adding 
`sarray<T>& sarray::operator = (array<T>* tab);`

it work in two stages, but not in one :-o

  `sarray<bool>   test;`
  `//sarray<bool> test = new array<bool>(2);// Compiler error`
  `test = new array<bool>(2);//OK`
  `sarray<bool>   test2 { new array<bool>(2) };//OK`

  `sarray<pRGB>     dummy;
  //sarray<pRGB>   dummy = new array<pRGB>(Side);//  Compiler error
  dummy = new array<pRGB>(Side);//OK
  sarray<pRGB>     dummy1 { new array<pRGB>(Side) };//OK`

Comment: @rustyx - ok, I have compilable example, but how to provide the file here?

Comment: @WojciechT.Borkowski "I have compilable example, but how to provide the file here?" - Just *edit* your question and paste the code.

Comment: @WojciechT.Borkowski your new code is better, but still pretty far from a [MRE]. There is still a lot of code that is completely irrelevant to your issue and is just noise, making it harder for us (and you) to see the problem. Here is a proper [MRE]: https://godbolt.org/z/jqo7aq I've reach this by removing one by one lines I suspected had nothing to do with the error; if the error message stayed exactly the same I left the line deleted, if it changed the error message I put it back in. That's what you should do before posting here. Anyway I voted to reopen and will answer if it gets reopened.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] your question with the [MRE] I've given you in the beginning of the question. You want ppl to first see the [MRE], not have to scroll through 2 screens to get to it. Since you have a proper [MRE] I would also delete the long verbose error message and just post the simple error message from the [MRE]. Keep the things simple and relevant.

Comment: Error is connected with this line:
`// When the following line is commented out the error disappers! `
     ` ptr< array<T> > _arr;//opaque smart ptr to array`

Comment: I have removed code that may be irrelevant. But the remaining may be.

Comment: OK. Your example is few line less :-) But any way I don't understand what happening.
Why `sarray<bool>   test3 { new array<bool>(2) };` is OK , but `sarray<bool>          test1 = new array<bool>(2);` is not?
The second syntax is important for me, because is much more similar to used always in Processing code.

Comment: When I added second constructor to `ptr<T>` : `ptr(const ptr<T>&);` it starts to compile. But such a constructor is rather impossible for smart pointer.

Comment: `X x = y;` is *copy-initialization*. It requires a copy constructor even if the copy is optimized away (until C++17).

Comment: @rustyx - but in my code y is from `new arrar<T>(...)` so in my opinion has type `array<T>*`, so i has provided constructor `sarray(array<T>* tab);`.  It was compilable until I introduced the line `ptr< array<T> > _arr;`.
This error remains until I add second constructor to `ptr<T>`:
 `ptr(const ptr<T>& other);`
This is strange because my code have nothing to do with `const` variables, and additionally implementation of smart pointer may need change  something inside parmeter `other`.

Answer (score 2):

`sarray<pAnt> dummy2 = new array<pAnt>(10);` is *copy-initialization* syntax.

Semantically it's similar to `sarray<pAnt> dummy2( sarray<pAnt>( new array<pAnt>(10) ) );` (until C++17).

`sarray` has no user-defined [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), so it gets an implicit one, which performs a member-wise copy.

The problem is, `ptr`, being one of the members, *does* have a user-defined copy constructor, `ptr(ptr<T>&)`. Technically a copy constructor can take a non-const reference. In practice it is [rarely useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683959/can-a-copy-constructor-take-a-non-const-parameter?noredirect=1&lq=1), because a non-const reference [will not bind to a temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object).

Hence the error - `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘...ptr<Ant>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘ptr<Ant>’`

A solution could be simple - change the awkward copy constructor into a move-constructor `ptr(ptr<T>&&)` (or add one).

Additional note: it seems `sarray` has a user-defined destructor. According to the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) it probably needs a user-defined copy and/or move-constructor, too.

Comment: Thank You. 
I'm a scientist, not a professional programmer, but I use C++ more than 20 years. Any way I have no idea that this kind of initialisation work so strange :-)