# Why does shared_ptr signature differ from unique_ptr for arrays?

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]); //ok

std::shared_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]); //Error

shared_ptr<int> sp( new int[10],[](int *p){delete [] p;});
                                       //Ok, writing custom deleter for
                                       //array since shared_ptr will call
                                       //delete by default.
```

Is there  any specific reason shared_ptr signature is different for arrays when compared to unique_ptr?

It would have been simpler if both api followed similar signature.

Comment: Another difference is that there is no `weak_ptr<>` for `unique_ptr<>`.

Comment: unique_ptr has a template specialization to allow the array while shared_ptr does not.

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array

Comment: If you need, it, you can use `std::shared_ptr<std::array<int>>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unique_ptr` has an [explicit](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/libstdc++/api/a00735.html) template specialization to handle array objects. The LWG (Library Working Group of the C++ committee) briefly considered the possibility of `shared_ptr<T[]>` but [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947579/why-isnt-there-a-stdshared-ptrt-specialisation) it wasn't of sufficiently high priority to make it into the standard, there was also some controversy over the consequences of the arithmetic on `shared_ptr<T[]>`