# SmartPointers and pointer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11

Good day! Little question about smart pointers. In general I have pointer to BYTE array and I want to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of plain pointer. Here my pointer example

```
shared_ptr<BYTE> pointer(new BYTE[100]);
LPBYTE *old_pointer = pointer;
```

Of course this is invalid example but how I can assign my smartpointer to other general pointer?

Comment: why don't you use a vector?

Comment: Sorry but I don't ask about vector or other containers. This is not real program example. I just try to understand usage of shared_ptr. LPBYTE = long pointer to BYTE = unsigned char far

Comment: Why would you want to assign the content of a smart pointer to a raw pointer and not another `shared_ptr`? Nevertheless use `std::shared_ptr::get()`

Comment: It is not possible to have shared_ptr of `[]`, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947579/why-isnt-there-a-stdshared-ptrt-specialisation)

Comment: I think `shared_ptr< std::array<BYTE, 100> >` would be OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably asking for

```
std::shared_ptr<std::array<BYTE,100>> pointer(make_shared<std::array<BYTE,100>>());
LPBYTE old_pointer = pointer.get()->data();
```

To have another reference you can simply have a statement like this

```
// increases reference count
std::shared_ptr<std::array<BYTE,100>> pointer2 = pointer;
```

See the detailed documentations here please: [`std::shared_ptr` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get).

**Though remember:**
Accessing the smart pointer's pointee using `std::shared_ptr::get()` bypasses the semantics and features provided by using the `std::shared_ptr`. That's highly discouraged, unless you very well know what you're doing with `old_pointer`, and if it's still in scope.

Comment: You should add that the OP shouldn't do this because it defeats the purpose of the shared pointer.

Comment: Yep, but as I know get() method will not rise reference counter, right?

Comment: @user922871 no, but if you want to do that then why are you trying to get a raw pointer to it?

Comment: Actually I don't try to get raw pointer, I just want to understand shared_ptr usage. So, if I want to increase reference counter then I must assign my pointer to another shared_ptr with same type? Otherwise RC will not be increased?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the raw pointer using get_pointer(shared_ptr<>)

BYTE* raw_pointer = get_pointer(pointer);

As others point out, grabbing the raw pointer means you now have a reference that isn't counted and have a potentially dangerous situation if not careful.

Also, if you use a shared_ptr<> to hold a pointer to a raw array, you need to call delete[] on the raw pointer rather than delete.  That means you'll need a custom deleter.  I realize your example is likely illustrative and not literal, but still thought it worthy to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0_b1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) can hold a dynamically allocated array.  That feature is being added to the [Library Fundamentals TS](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4081.html#memory.smartptr.shared) (part of the standardization process).