# Why is there no [] operator for std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I wonder what the rationale is behind the fact, that `std::shared_ptr` does not define the `[]` operator for arrays. In particular why does `std::unique_ptr` feature this operator but not `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: `unique_ptr` has a specialization that manages arrays, `shared_ptr` doesn't. `operator[]` is only provided for that specialization. Are you asking why `shared_ptr` doesn't have that?

Comment: I hope this answers your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947579/why-isnt-there-a-stdshared-ptrt-specialisation

Comment: @juanchopanza I suppose I am.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` only defines `operator[]` in a specialization for arrays: `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. For non-array pointers, the operator[] doesn't make much sense anyways (only `[0]`).

Such a specialization for `std::shared_ptr` is missing (in C++11), which is discussed in the related question: [Why isn't there a std::shared_ptr<T[]> specialisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947579/why-isnt-there-a-stdshared-ptrt-specialisation)

You should not use a non-array smart pointer with array allocation, unless you provide a custom deleter. In particular, `unique_ptr<int> p = new int[10]` is bad, since it calls `delete` instead of `delete[]`. Use `unique_ptr<int[]>` instead, which calls `delete[]`. (And this one implements `operator[]`). If you're using `shared_ptr` to hold a `T[]`, you need to use a custom deleter. See also [shared_ptr to an array : should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used) -- but it doesn't provide `operator[]`, since it uses type erasure to distinguish between array and non-array (the smart pointer type is independent of the provided deleter).

If you wonder why there is no `shared_ptr` specialization for arrays: that was a proposal, but wasn't included in the standard (mainly since **you can work around by writing `ptr.get() + i` for `ptr[i]`**).

Comment: `shared_ptr` uses the `delete` _you_ provide (if you provide one); it's quite possible to provide something like `[]( T* p ) { delete[] p; }`.

Comment: Yeah, that's mainly regarding `unique_ptr`, since changing the deleter for that pointer changes the type (no type erasure there). And for `shared_ptr`, we already have a specialization which handles `delete[]`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Updated, I hope it is clearer now...

Comment: After working a long time on getting shared_ptr of c-style arrays to work as I wanted, I decided in the end it was just easier to make my own simple dynamic array container (that uses a smart pointer within) and then allocate a single instance of the container using make_shared instead.