# Initialization of shared_ptr<T> from unique_ptr<T[]>

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, c++14, unique-ptr

[Followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196790/why-does-stdshared-ptrt-stdunique-ptrt-compile-while-stdshared-pt) question]

I've been dealing a little bit with smart pointers to c-style arrays recently. I ultimately wound up doing the recommended thing and using smart pointers to vectors instead, but during that period, I got a bit of advice: don't use a `shared_ptr<T>` object to manage an array initially made with `make_unique<T[]>` because it won't call `delete[]` but rather `delete`.

This didn't seem logical to me, and I checked both [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/944684de57f98b80) and the Standard:

---

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "start!\n";
    auto customArrayAllocator = [](unsigned int num){
        std::cout << "custom array allocator\n";
        return new int[num];
    };

    std::cout << "allocator constructed\n";

    auto customArrayDeleter = [](int *ptr){
        std::cout << "custom array deleter\n";
        delete[] ptr;
    };

    std::cout << "deleter constructed\n";

    std::unique_ptr<int[], decltype(customArrayDeleter)>
        myUnique(customArrayAllocator(4), customArrayDeleter);

    std::cout << "unique_ptr constructed\n";

    std::shared_ptr<int>
        myShared = std::move(myUnique);

    std::cout << "shared_ptr constructed\n";
}
```

produces this output:

```
start!
allocator constructed
deleter constructed
custom array allocator
unique_ptr constructed
shared_ptr constructed
custom array deleter
```

Which seems to indicate that the `unique_ptr<T[]>`'s deleter is passed to the `shared_ptr<T>`, as I expected.

---

From the C++14 Standard § 20.8.2.2.1 [pg. 571 of doc, 585 of pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

> **template  shared_ptr(unique_ptr&& r);**
>   *Remark*: This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless unique_ptr::pointer
>   is convertible to T*.
>   *Effects*: Equivalent to shared_ptr(r.release(), r.get_deleter()) when D is not a reference type,
>   otherwise shared_ptr(r.release(), ref(r.get_deleter())).
>   *Exception safety*: If an exception is thrown, the constructor has no effect.

If I'm reading that right, it means that a `shared_ptr` object constructs itself from both the pointer and the deleter of a `unique_ptr`. Furthermore, it's my understanding (from the answer to the original question) that the `::pointer` type of `unique_ptr<T[]>` is `T*`, which should be convertible to `shared_ptr<T>::pointer`'s `T*`. So the deleter should just be copied right from the `unique_ptr` object, right?

---

Did my test only work because it's not actually equivalent to the function of `std::make_shared<T[]>`, or is the syntax

```
std::shared_ptr<T> mySharedArray = std::make_unique<T[]>(16);
```

a good, exception safe (and cleaner) alternative to

```
std::shared_ptr<T> mysharedArray(new T[16], [](T* ptr){delete[] ptr;});
```

and its ilk, when I am unable to use Boost's [shared array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) and desire to avoid including either the `vector` or the `array` header with my code?

Comment: N.B. although the array is guaranteed to be correctly deleted, there is a potential safety problem when converting `unique_ptr<Derived[]>` -> `shared_ptr<Derived>` -> `shared_ptr<Base>`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/32483375/981959

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your example is valid for the very reasons you've stated. `unique_ptr::pointer` is `int *`, and you're trying to pass ownership of that to a `shared_ptr<int>`, so the converting constructor you've listed will participate in overload resolution, and will make a copy of the deleter (`std::default_delete<int[]>`) because it's not a reference type.

So the following is valid, and will call `delete[]` when the `shared_ptr` reference count goes to zero

```
std::shared_ptr<T> mySharedArray = std::make_unique<T[]>(16);
```

Another way to write this, other than the lambda you've shown, is

```
std::shared_ptr<T> mySharedArray(new T[16], std::default_delete<int[]>());
```

which will result in `mySharedArray` acquiring the same deleter as the previous line.