# shared_ptr from unique_ptr to an array

Tags: c++, c++11

Scott Meyers mentions in his book, *Effective Modern C++*, that using `shared_ptr` to arrays is discouraged because when converted to Base class pointers it creates "holes" in the type system.

However, it is possible to create `shared_ptr<T>` from `unique_ptr<T[]>` in the following way

```
std::shared_ptr<D> pDerived = std::shared_ptr<D>(std::make_unique<D[]>(3)); // Create an array of 3 D's
```

Is the above code potentially dangerous? Are there pitfalls if `pDerived` is later copied into a `pBase`?

```
std::shared_ptr<B> pBase = pDerived; // B is the base class for D
```

Comment: Re-opened because http://stackoverflow.com/q/30495941/981959 only talks about the first question, not upcasting to `shared_ptr<B>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the above code potentially dangerous?

It depends what you do with it.

It won't leak resources because the `default_delete<D[]>` that uses `delete[]` will be copied from the `unique_ptr` and stored in the `shared_ptr` (as described at [Initialization of shared_ptr<T> from unique_ptr<T[]>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30495941/981959)).

> Are there pitfalls if `pDerived` is later copied into a `pBase`?

Yes, if you do something like `pBase.get()[1]` then that is not a valid pointer to the second element if `sizeof(B) != sizeof(D)`

`std::experimental::shared_ptr` from the [Library Fundamentals TS](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v2/fundamentals-ts.html#memory.smartptr) supports arrays properly (as proposed by [N3939](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3939.html)).

With the version in the TS, `shared_ptr<D>` does not allow construction from a `unique_ptr<D[]>`, but `shared_ptr<D[]>` does. A `shared_ptr<D[]>` cannot be converted to `shared_ptr<B[]>`, to avoid the safety problem you refer to.

The support for arrays might make it into `std::shared_ptr` in a future C++ standard, but is only in the TS for now.