# Assigning make_unique<X> to shared_ptr<X>

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, move-assignment-operator

I (erroneously) had the following assignment in my program:

```
std::shared_ptr<SI::Program> m_program; // in class

m_program = std::make_unique<SI::Program>(); // in method
```

When I found this, I first wondered why this even compiles. It turns out the `shared_ptr` has a special move assignment operator for `unique_ptr` objects.

My question is, is this therefore always safe to do, or does it have any implications?

(Safe as for the code execution; it is obviously not safe for a code review...)

Comment: one reason to do this might be to take advantage of `unique_ptr`'s array specialization, which `shared_ptr` lacks. [This *does* create a safety problem though.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483375/shared-ptr-from-unique-ptr-to-an-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is "safe" to do so in a sense that you won't have any double-deleting or other problems.

It is not OK to do so because:

1. It's misleading - `make_unique` is used to make unique pointers, not shared.
2. It's wasteful - `make_unique` will only allocate the object, not the associated control block. that will force the `shared_ptr` constructor to allocate the control block itself. `std::make_shared` allocate them both in one allocation, which is much more efficient.

Comment: "*It's misleading - make_unique is used to make unique pointers, not shared.*" If the committee thought it was misleading to be able to upgrade unique ownership into shared ownership, they wouldn't have given `shared_ptr` a specific constructor to do exactly that.

Comment: @NicolBolas The upgrading might generally be ok, but written like I did, it certainly has some WTF factor to it

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's perfectly safe; `shared_ptr` has a constructor that can transfer ownership from a `unique_ptr` by move. Though it's not as efficient as calling `make_shared` properly.