# Access child class in array of base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers, rtti

I have an array of base classes, the items thereof contain a child class.  The problem is that when I try to access the child class in the array I get the error `no operator "[]" matches these operands` when I try to do:

```
shared_ptr<P>& tmpP= (*arrayOfC)[(int)x][(int)y];
```

I am trying to access the child class.  If I do:

```
arrayOfC[(int)x][(int)y]
```

then i can access the base class which is not what I am after.
I have tried using dynamic_cast to no avail.

The array is

```
shared_ptr<C> arrayOfC[800][600];
```

This is declared in another header file and does use forward declaration as well.
This is how its being saved:

```
shared_ptr<P> childClassP= make_shared<P>(z, x, y);
arrayOfC[(int)x][(int)y] = std::move(childClassP);
```

Comment: `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`? - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/

Comment: I tried that but where would I use it, I think i used it wrong.

Comment: `auto tmpC_derived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<C_derived>(arrayOfC_base[x][y]);` should do it.

Comment: Is C the base class or the child class?

Comment: C is the base class, there are two child classes.

Comment: @Den-Jason that didn't quite do it.

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail in your question.

Comment: I was editing as we speak to show how its being saved as well.

Comment: You appear to have a split personality between unique and shared pointers......
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022001/assigning-make-uniquex-to-shared-ptrx

Comment: `make_unique`, as the name suggests, makes a `unique_ptr` not a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Apologies i have been making changes from unique to shared but that still didn't fix the issue

Comment: Is there any extra info i can provide its a personal project so nothing is off limits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, plus, you also need to have at the very least, a virtual destructor in the base class in order to generate vtables to make the classes polymorphically related.

```
#include <memory>

struct C {
    virtual ~C() {}
};

struct P : public C {

};

std::shared_ptr<C> arrayOfC[8][6];

int main() {
    auto derived_ptr = std::make_shared<P>();
    int x {2};
    int y {2};
    arrayOfC[x][y] = std::move(derived_ptr);

    // does not compile: std::shared_ptr<P> view = arrayOfC[x][y];

    std::shared_ptr<P> view = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<P>(arrayOfC[x][y]);

    return 0;
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/dynamic_pointer_cast/

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/qn9oq4zfb