# Making and accessing shared ptr array

Tags: c++, arrays

Just a quick query regarding `shared_ptr`:

so i have this code:

`std::shared_ptr<int> asd(new int[10]);`

From my understanding, i am making a single `shared_ptr<int>` that points to an array of 10 integers. 
if my understading is correct then here are my questions:

1.) How do i access the values/initialize ?

2.) Is it possible to use make_shared?

3.) What if i want to make an array of 10 shared_ptr and make them point to a single int?

I am also aware that i need to supply a custom deleter when i deal with arrays using shared_ptr. Using vectors will also make it easier.

Comment: I would also like to know how to access the values.

Comment: This isn't really possible in C++ without shenanigans.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947579/why-isnt-there-a-stdshared-ptrt-specialisation

Comment: I don't think this is really a dupe. It doesn't ask whether you should use or not a shared_ptr, but how to use it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is a very very bad idea. You are creating indeed an array of `10` `int`s, but the default deleter uses `delete` instead of `delete[]` to deallocate the memory. You either have to specify a custom deleter,

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<int> asd(new int[10]{0}, [](int* _p)
   {
       delete[] _p;
   }); // also zero-initializes
   ```

   or use

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<int[]> asd(new int[10]{0}); // no need for a deleter here
   ```

   instead, as `unique_ptr` has an array specialization, and the deleter uses the proper `delete[]` for this specialization. The examples above zero-initialize the dynamically allocated arrays. If you want other values, then dereference the pointers and set the values, as you'd do in a raw pointer situation. To access the value in the array pointed by a `shared_ptr`, you cannot use `arr[j]` syntax anymore, as `shared_ptr` does not overload `operator[]`. You need to get the managed raw pointer and use it like

   ```
   *(asd.get()+2) // this dereference the third element
   ```

   or

   ```
   asd.get()[2] // same as above
   ```

   As you can see, `shared_ptr` is not really made for arrays. On the other hand, `unique_ptr` overloads `operator[]` for its managed array, so you can simply use `asd[2]` to refer to the third element in the array.
2. You cannot use `make_shared`, as `make_shared` does not allow you to specify the deleter.
3. Simply create an array of 10 `shared_ptr` from an initial `shared_ptr` that points to your desired `int`

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int{42});
   std::array<std::shared_ptr<int>, 10> arr_sp;
   for(auto& elem: arr_sp)
       elem = sp;
   ```

   **DO NOT** construct all elements of the array from the same **raw** pointer, as you end up with multiple `shared_ptr`s managing the same raw pointer, which is always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for a precise answer but with regards to question#1, how do i access the shared_ptr's value if ever? because asd[0] gives me error