# C++11 : Why array with shared_ptr can not be deleted by default

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Reading : The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference

I came across with following piece :

> Note that the default deleter provided by shared_ptr calls delete, not
>   delete[]. This means that the default deleter is appropriate only if a
>   shared pointer owns a single object created with new. Unfortunately,
>   creating a shared_ptr for an array is possible but wrong:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int[10]); // ERROR, but compiles
```

> So, if you use new[] to create an array of objects you have to define
>   your own deleter. You can do that by passing a function, function
>   object, or lambda, which calls delete[ ] for the passed ordinary
>   pointer. For example:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int[10],
[](int* p) {
delete[] p;
});
```

Is there any specific reason behind this limitation? If shared pointer is smart, can't it be that smart that it keeps the info whether it's array or single object?

Though there is a way to do this :

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>());
```

Comment: new returns a pointer, therefore the smart_ptr cannot know if the passed ptr belongs to a single instance or an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947579/why-isnt-there-a-stdshared-ptrt-specialisation

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `new int[10]` and `new int` return the same type: `int*`, so there is nothing to do any overloading on. It's a limitation inherited from `C`, and there isn't much that can be done about it.

Normally you would just use a container instead of directly allocating though, so it isn't usually an issue.

edit: as Richard says, and as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947579/why-isnt-there-a-stdshared-ptrt-specialisation), it seems sensible that `std::shared_ptr<int[]>` would do as you want, since `std::unique_ptr` has a similar overload, and storing an actual pointer to an `int[]` would be kind of redundant (in any case, you could use `std::shared_ptr<int*>` if you *really* wanted to).

I still think that using `default_deleter<int[]>` is the best way to go as it is.

Comment: There's no way to tell from just a pointer how that pointer was allocated.

Comment: i may be mixing up things, but if that's the issue how compiler(32-bit word size) get to know that for "new int" - 4 bytes, for "new int[10]" - 44 bytes need to be allocated.

Comment: @instance The compiler knows how much memory to allocate, but the allocated size can be rounded up by the OS, so it only has an upper bound on the actual requested size. Also, if you call new Object, thecompiler allocates just enough space for Object, and returns ptr to it. If you call new Object[10], then compiler allocates first a count (i,.e. 10), then the 10 Objects (so it knows how many destructors to call). Then it returns ptr to first object. But just given the ptr, it can't assume that (ptr-8) is anything but random memory, so it can't tell if it was from new or new[] reliably.

Comment: Arguably, the compiler could allocate always memory for the counter and use a special value (eg 1) when allocating an object instead of an array. But you will be paying an overhead for every single call to `new`, and it is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks to me to be an omission in the standard. There is indeed a specialisation for array handling in `std::unique_ptr` so one might expect there to be one for `std::shared_ptr` (perhaps someone who has served on the comittee can comment?)

Here is an idiomatic way to correctly create your shared array:

```
#include <memory>

auto make_shared_array(std::size_t size)
{
    // create unique_ptr with correct deleter
    auto p = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);

    // take ownership of the data and a copy of the correct deleter.
    auto sp = std::shared_ptr<int>(p.release(), p.get_deleter());

    return sp;
}


int main()
{
    auto sp = make_shared_array(10);
}
```