# Allocating class member with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Is my assumption, that in following example, memory referenced by `b` will be deallocated once instance of `A` goes out of scope at end of `func()`, correct?

```
class A{
public:
   A() {
        b = std::shared_ptr<char>(new char[100] { 0 } );
   }
   char* b;
}

void func {
   A a;
}
```

Comment: I would double check that using `shared_ptr` with an array in that fashion is correct. Maybe it is, I'm not sure.

Comment: @NeilKirk, `shared_ptr<T[]>` has been proposed for C++17. I thought I saw somewhere that it was accepted, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @NeilKirk: According to [this, definitely not safe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266443/can-you-use-a-shared-ptr-for-raii-of-c-style-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not correct. `b` is of type `char *` and you assign to it a `shared_ptr<char>`. You should get a compilation error.

Furthermore, the constructor is `private`, another compilation error.

And how do you access `b` in `func()`? It is private in `A`.

Obviously your exercise is incomplete... so I just go from what you provided.

Also I suggest to use `unique_ptr` in case you can say it is a unique ownership (which it appears to be in my opinion).

This compiles:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:

    A() {
        std::cout << "A created with unique pointer" << std::endl;
        b = std::unique_ptr<char>(new char[100] {
            0
        });
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "A destroyed" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<char> b;
};

void func() {
    A a;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Call func()" << std::endl;
    func();
    std::cout << "func() called" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And at the end of `func()` `A` is destroyed and with it the `unique_ptr`.

However, ask yourself if you really need to use pointer? In your case an automatic variable should be just fine; it does the same (i.e. being destroyed when `func()` exits.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning to a `char*` member, so I'm pretty sure the `shared_ptr` is cleaned up as soon as the assignment completes (because it wasn't stored to another `shared_ptr` that would maintain the reference count).

If you want to use `shared_ptr`s, you have to use them consistently; a raw pointer class member can't manage anything for you. The pointer is still initialized to where the memory was allocated, but it's not allocated anymore; accessing it even a line later in the constructor would be undefined behavior/a use-after-free bug.

In any event, not safe [because default `shared_ptr` uses `delete`, not `delete[]`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266443/can-you-use-a-shared-ptr-for-raii-of-c-style-arrays) Is there some reason a `std::shared_ptr<std::array<char, 100>>` couldn't be used?

Comment: so assigning it to `b` doesn't increases `shared_ptr`'s ref count? And why does  `std::shared_ptr<std::array<char, 100>>`  work correctly?