# How to take ownership of std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

This is follow-up question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428166/allocating-class-member-with-stdshared-ptr).

How do we take ownership of a std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr?

Is there a way to to keep `b` alive?

```
class A{
  public:
   A() {
        b = std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[100] { 0 });
   }
 char* b;
}

void func {
   A a;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To take ownership of the pointer, use [`std::unique_ptr::release()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release):

> Releases the ownership of the managed object if any.
>
> **Return value**. Pointer to the managed object or `nullptr` if there was no managed object, i.e. the value which would be returned by [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) before the call.

---

That being said, I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do `b = std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[100] { 0 }).release();`. Maybe what you want is this, i.e. have `A` itself store the `unique_ptr`?

```
class A {
    A() : b(new char[100] { 0 }) { }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> b;
}
```

Now, whenever an `A` instance is destructed, the memory pointed to by `A.b` will be freed.