# compiler won't compile smart pointer using -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, compiler-errors, smart-pointers

I'm trying to compile a simple shared pointer declaration but using `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main` using cmd but due to some reasons it throws a bunch of errors. I tried finding similar questions on Stack Overflow but none of them matches my problem.

code:

```
std::shared_ptr<int[]>array(new int[100]);
```

Header files:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
```

compiler version: g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Error:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\memory:82,
                 from main.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of 'std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = int; _Tp = int []; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\shared_ptr.h:117:32:   required from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = int; _Tp = int []]'
main.cpp:7:42:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\shared_ptr_base.h:885:39: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[]' in initialization
         : _M_ptr(__p), _M_refcount(__p)
                                       ^`
```

I'm relatively new and don't know what this error means.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Consider a `shared_ptr` to a `std::array` as a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to `C++17`, `std::shared_ptr` could **not** handle dynamically allocated arrays. Upgrade your compiler to support `C++17` and your code will happily compile.

EDIT: There **is** a workaround for earlier versions. You *could* use:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[10], custom_deleter<int>{});
```

where `custom_deleter` will be a function that will be used to free the allocated memory. In this case, simple `delete[]` (instead of implicit `delete` inside `shared_ptr`s destructor) will be enough:

```
template< typename T >
struct custom_deleter
{
    void operator ()(const T* arr)
    { 
        delete[] arr; 
    }
};
```

but since you are already using `C++11`, one could replace the struct with a *lambda expression*, which will simplify the code:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[10], [](const int* arr){ delete[] arr; });
```

Comment: Can you suggest any links where I could download c++17 compiler ?

Comment: There is no such  thing as a "c++17" compiler - just implementations that support the standard to a lesser or greater extent, such as https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhan It looks like library support for `shared_ptr<T[]>` requires at least gcc 7.1

Answer (score 1):

The "cannot convert ..." error is a type error, it means that you've used the wrong data type. In this case, it's specifically telling you that the constructor for `std::shared_ptr<int[]>` wants a `int (*)[]` argument type, but you're providing an argument of type `int *`. Since the compiler doesn't know how to convert from `int *` to `int (*)[]`, you're getting this error.

In any case, [you shouldn't be using `shared_ptr` to manage C-style arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266443/can-you-use-a-shared-ptr-for-raii-of-c-style-arrays). I'd advise switching to STL containers, either `std::array<int, N>` or `std::vector<int>` depending on whether you know the size at compile time or not. Any STL container type can then be put into a smart pointer, if you like.