# Smart Pointers(shared_ptr)

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

i try to learn how to use smart pointers. I use for the long time normal pointers and i think i need some upgrade of my skills.

I make some research, i understand some aspects of smart pointers, but i try to implement in a clear project to see how smart pointers work. I try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity called!" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity destroyed!" << std::endl;
    }
    void print() { std::cout << "Message!"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int>f1(new int[100]);

    f1.get()[1] = 1;
    std::cout << f1.get()[1];
}
```

all good, message it's print. But when i try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity called!" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity destroyed!" << std::endl;
    }
    void print() { std::cout << "Message!"; };
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Entity>f1(new Entity[100]);

    f1.get()[1].print();
}
```

I get this error:
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMDIZ.png

next:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Entity>f1(new Entity[100]);

    (f1.get() + 1)->print();
}
```

same error.

I try to use std::make_shared:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity called!" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity destroyed!" << std::endl;
    }
    void print() { std::cout << "Message!"; };
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Entity>f1 = std::make_shared<Entity>();

    f1->print();
}
```

everything it's ok.

I try to alocate continue memory with int:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity called!" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity destroyed!" << std::endl;
    }
    void print() { std::cout << "Message!"; };
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int>f1 = std::make_shared<int>(100);

    f1.get()[1] = 10;
    std::cout << f1.get()[1];
}
```

message it's printed, output: 10
but error:
[https://i.imgur.com/UPu7VZo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vrb9.png)

i try in another way:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int>f1 = std::make_shared<int>(100);

    *(f1.get() +1) = 10;
    std::cout << *(f1.get() + 1);
}
```

same error.

```
std::shared_ptr<Entity[]>f1 = std::make_shared<Entity[]>(new Entity[100]);
```

i have error...

What i try to make something like this:

```
int main()
{
    Entity* f1 = new Entity[100];

    f1[0].print();
    f1[1].print();
    f1[2].print();

}
```

but i want to use smart pointers.

for int i want to make some assigned value like this:

```
int main()
{
    int* f1 = new int[100];

    f1[0] = 14;
    f1[1] = 20;
    f1[2] = 5;
}
```

How can i make something like this with smart pointers. I want to use: std::make_shared(new Entity[100]) or something like this.

I can try with library like vector or array but i don't want to use this library for the moment. I want to keep my code clear for the moment. After i understand 100% smart pointers i will use array and vector library

Comment: Error messages are text. Paste the text here; don't link to an image of text.

Comment: You should use `std::shared_ptr<Entity[]>` or the container will try to call `delete` instead of `delete[]` which is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shared\_ptr to an array : should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used)

Comment: `make_shared` creates ("makes") a shared object. It does not take a pointer to an object and "make it shared".

Comment: While `std::shared_ptr<Entity[]>` is possible, `std::vector<Entity>` and `std::array<Entity, 100>` are more common. Smart pointers are only one of the replacements of dumb pointers. The standard containers are another replacement.

Comment: any reason why you wouldn't use `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 5):

Not

```
std::shared_ptr<Entity[]> f1 = std::make_shared<Entity[]>(new Entity[100]);
```

but

```
std::shared_ptr<Entity[]> f1 = std::make_shared<Entity[]>(100);
```

or even simpler

```
auto f1 = std::make_shared<Entity[]>(100);
```

When you use `make_shared` you should not use `new`. One of the points of `make_shared` is to allocate memory more efficiently that it would be if you used `new`.

Note: the array form of `make_shared` requires C++20.

Comment: I have errorrs :warning C4200: nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union

Comment: What line of code does that error refer to? What version of C++ are you compiling to?

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries what compiler are you using?

Comment: IDE it's visual studio comunity, but i think it's C++2017/2020

Comment: i compilate:int main()
{
 std::shared_ptr<Entity[]>f1 = std::make_shared<Entity[]>(100);

} and after:https://pastebin.com/3mEjjb8W

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries in visual studio you need to set according to what version of standard the compiler compiles your code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries Apparently using an array type in make_shared is not supported until C++20, apologies.

Comment: @Öö Tiib it's C++17;

Comment: @john i use c++17

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries: For C++17, see NadavS's answer. It's slightly more verbose. (Or use `std::vector<Entity>`, which is supported since 1998)

Comment: using shared_ptr with arrays is just bad practice.

Comment: @Waqar why? tell me more, i want to understand that

Comment: This post explains is much better than I ever could: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266443/can-you-use-a-shared-ptr-for-raii-of-c-style-arrays

Comment: @Waqar That post is out of date, since C++11 shared_ptr can safely be used on arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The code sample that should work for you is:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Entity[]>f1(new Entity[100]);

    f1.get()[1].print();
}
```

As for `make_shared`, you're out of luck - the current CPP standard, 17, doesn't seem to support it (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)
However, make_shared is only used to eliminate a race condition in allocation and can be implemented manually or just omitted. I encourage reading more about it.

Comment: your code work..
but i don't understand exacly:
auto sp = std::make_shared<C>(12);
 
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(sp), std::shared_ptr<C>>);
 
    std::cout << sp->i << '\n';

in my case C++17:
auto f2 = std::make_shared<Entity[]>(100); //compile without errors
how can i acces f2.get()[1].printf()?
i need to make static_assert?

Comment: and question 2: how can i take care about  race condition in allocation, how can i implement manual?

Comment: I don't understand question 1.

Comment: In question 2, the issue is that if the constructor of `shared_ptr` fails you leak your allocation. AFAIK, the code to solve it is:

Comment: shared_ptr<T> p;
T* temp_ptr = new T();
try {
  p = temp_ptr;
} catch(...) {
  delete temp_ptr;
  throw;
}

Comment: question 1: i see an exemple on cppreference :  auto sp = std::make_shared<C>(12); how can i get the acces on sp[1] sp[2]?

Comment: in this example, if I understand correcty, there is only one `C`, not an array of `C` s. Therefore, it is not what you're looking fore.